# What PHP needs to work with gettext?

Tags: php, linux, gettext, php-gettext

I have a linux server with PHP. I do not see `gettext` in the PHPINFO output, so I assume `gettext` is not enabled or included in the PHP. I have installed the `gettext` lib on the machine.
What other steps do I need to do to enable `gettext` in my PHP?

I read the [php.net](http://www.php.net/) documentation, the only entry there writes about building PHP with `gettext`. Is this the only way, or is there another simpler way?

Comment: What distribution of Linux are you running on the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your linux distrubution likely has a pre-compiled package for it (RPM on Redhat and derivative or DEB on Debian and its derivatives). Typically you'll need to install the package and you'll have to restart apache if you're using mod_php (as opposed to running it in CGI mode)

Comment: PCKG for gettext only or the entire PHP compiled with it?

Answer (score 2):

Requirements: http://www.php.net/manual/en/gettext.requirements.php

Installation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/gettext.installation.php

Comment: Thanks, but I try another solution beside recompiling PHP, edited my question to show I am familiar with those docs.